# Mi funcion heredada en javaScript no me devuelte lo que quiero

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Estoy tratando de hacer una función heredada que me devuelva los valores que quiero pero no puedo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías colocar el código para poder copiarlo, no en una imagen, asi facilitas a quien responde para poder probar tu código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 // viendo el codigo a ojo, veo que el la el método que llamas en el "document.write" es celinfo, y tendría que ser cel2.mostrarInfo...Exitos!//
```

```js
class Celular {
    constructor(color, peso, tamaño, rdc, ram) {
        this.color = color;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.tamaño = tamaño;
        this.resolucionDeCamara = rdc;
        this.memoriaRam = ram;
        this.encendido = false;
    }
    presionarBotonEncendido() {
        if (this.encendido == false) {
            alert("celular prendido");
            this.encendido = true;
        } else {
            alert("celular apagado");
            this.encendido = false;
        }
    }

    reiniciar() {
        if (this.encendido == true) {
            alert("reiniciando celular");
        } else {
            alert("el celular está apagado");
        }
    }
    tomarFoto() {
        alert(`foto tomada en una resolución de: ${this.resolucionDeCamara}`);
    }
    grabarVideo() {
        alert(`grabando video en ${this.resolucionDeCamara}`);
    }
    mobileInfo() {
        return `
        Color: <b>${this.color}</b></br>
        Peso: <b>${this.peso}</b></br>
        Tamaño: <b>${this.tamaño}</b></br>
        Memoria Ram: <b>${this.memoriaRam}</b></br>
        Resolución de Video: <b>${this.resolucionDeCamara}</b></br>
        `;
    }
}


class CelularAltaGama extends Celular {
    constructor(color, peso, tamaño, rdc, ram, rdce) {
        super(color, peso, tamaño, rdc, ram);
        this.resolucionDeCamaraExtra = rdce;
    }
    grabarVideoLento() {
        alert("estas grabando en camara lenta");
    }
    reconocmientoFacial() {
        alert("vamos a iniciar un reconocimiento facial")
    }
    infoAltaGama() {
        return this.mobileInfo() + `Resolución de Camara Extra: ${this.resolucionDeCamaraExtra}`;
    }
}


// celular1 = new Celular("rojo","150g","5'","hd","1GB");
// celular2 = new Celular("negro","155g","5.4'","full hd","2GB");
// celular3 = new Celular("blanco","15046g","5.9'","full hd","2GB");

// celular1.presionarBotonEncendido();
// celular1.tomarFoto();
// celular1.grabarVideo();
// celular1.reiniciar();
// celular1.presionarBotonEncendido();

celular1 = new CelularAltaGama("rojo", "130g", "5.2", "4K", "3GB", "full hd");
celular2 = new CelularAltaGama("negro", "142g", "6", "4K", "4GB", "hd");


document.write(`
    ${celular1.infoAltaGama()} <br><br>
    ${celular2.infoAltaGama()} <br>
    `);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script src="./rodri.js"></script>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```